# Pass parameter to initState

Tags: dart, flutter, widget, stateful

Look at this code - widget to fetch data and display on list:

```
class _MyEventsFragmentState extends State <MyEventsFragment>{

  var events;

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    events = fetchEvents(true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<EventsResponse>(
          future: events,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                helpers.logout(context, Strings.msg_session_expired);
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return new Container(color: Colors.white,
                  child: new ListControl().build(snapshot));
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

`fetchEvent` method has parameter to indicate which events I need to fetch. If set to true, - my events, if set to false - all events returned. Above code loads my events and `fetchEvents` is called inside `initState` override to avoid unnecesary data reloading.

To fetch all events I defined another class:

```
class EventsFragment extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EventsFragmentState createState() => new _EventsFragmentState();
}

class _EventsFragmentState extends State <EventsFragment>{

  var events;

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    events = fetchEvents(false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<EventsResponse>(
          future: events,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                helpers.logout(context, Strings.msg_session_expired);
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return new Container(color: Colors.white,
                  child: new ListControl().build(snapshot));
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

But this is very dumb solution, because code is almost the same. So I tried to pass boolean value to indicate which events to load, something like that:

```
@override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    events = fetchEvents(isMyEvents);
  }
```

`isMyEvents` should be got from `EventsFragment` constructor. However, it won't be accesible inside `initState`. Ho to pass it properly? I could access it inside `build` override, but not inside `initState`. How to pass it properly and make sure it will be refreshed every time widget instance is created?

[edit]

So this how I solved my problem (it seems to be fine):

```
class EventsFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventsFragment({Key key, this.isMyEvent}) : super(key: key);

  final bool isMyEvent;

  @override
  _EventsFragmentState createState() => new _EventsFragmentState();
}

class _EventsFragmentState extends State <EventsFragment>{

  var events;

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    events = fetchEvents(widget.isMyEvent);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(EventsFragment oldWidget) {

    if(oldWidget.isMyEvent != widget.isMyEvent)
      events = fetchEvents(widget.isMyEvent);

    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<EventsResponse>(
          future: events,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                helpers.logout(context, Strings.msg_session_expired);
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return new Container(color: Colors.white,
                  child: new ListControl().build(snapshot));
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: keep your params as `final` fields inside `EventsFragment`

Comment: It won't be accesible from state

Comment: yes it will, see `State#widget` property

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass such parameter to the `StatefulWidget` subclass, and use that field instead

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Foo({Key key, this.isMyEvent}) : super(key: key);

  final bool isMyEvent;

  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.isMyEvent);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `initState()` is called only one time, so my data won't be refreshed if I first pass isMyEvent as true, then second time as false. How to force reset state from outsite my widget?

Comment: I mean flutter caches my widget. So if I want to show it again, with changed `isMyEvent` value, still data is refreshed with previous `isMyEvent` value.

Comment: use `didUpdateWidget`

Comment: How to use it? I added `didUpdateWidget(widget);` to `initState` and I am still getting the same issue

Comment: I updated my question, please let me know if it's valid solution.